# jquery AJAX call with slider

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Is it possible to make an AJAX slider
with a jQuery AJAX call to the ASP.NET server,

this is HTML:

```
<ul id="comments" runat="server">

</ul>
```

I don't want the user posting a comment and seeing the slide in li in his own page. The slide in must be visible to anyone browsing the website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with a small amount of JS and some CSS.
Change
`comments.InnerHtml += "<li>" + dr.GetString(0) + "</li>";`
to
`comments.InnerHtml += "<li class=\"hide\">" + dr.GetString(0) + "</li>";`

along with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'WebForm1.aspx',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#comments').html(data);
            updateC();
        }
    });
});
function updateC(){
    var d = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');
    if(d.length > 1){
        for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i++){
            d[i].setAttribute('class','');
        }
    }
}
```

Then, add a `style` tag with the following inside:

```
.hide{
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s forwards;     /*'0.5s' is the animation time*/
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;              /*Delay before the animation*/
    animation: slide 0.5s forwards;             /*'0.5s' is the animation time*/
    animation-delay: 0.5s;                      /*Delay before the animation*/
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide{
    100% { height: 20px; }                      /*Set 20px to the line-height*/
}
@keyframes slide{
    100% { height: 20px; }                      /*Set 20px to the line-height*/
}
```

Of course, you may want to change the CSS depending on delays, timing and height settings, but that is a scaffold that works fine.

Comment: The HTML `li` tags will not be classified as such until the `hide` class is removed. If you do not need the points along the side of the list to be displayed, then you will not be required to remove the `hide` class, and the JS edit (excluding the `class=\"hide\"` change) can be discarded and will function as intended.